# Joining 2 mysql tables and generating an array

Tags: php, mysql

entries and images and have been trying every way I can find to join them to get the below result

```
entries:
entry_id
name

images:
entry_id
image_url
```

I'm using php and would like to be able to retrieve all associated image_url rows for a given entry_id and combine them with the other information from the entries table.

So I have something like:

```
entries:
1, Brian
2, Steve
3, Jane

images:
1, images/brian1.jpg
1, images/brian2.jpg
2, images/steve.jpg
3, images/jane_1.jpg
3, images/jane_2.jpg
3, images/jane_3.jpg
```

And would like to get an array back something like

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
    array(3) {
      ["entry_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Brian"
      ["images"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["image_url"]=>
          string(17) "images/brian1.jpg"
          ["image_url"]=>
          string(17) "images/brian2.jpg"
        }
      }
  [1]=>
    array(3) {
      ["entry_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Steve"
      ["images"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["image_url"]=>
          string(16) "images/steve.jpg"
        }
      }
  [2]=>
    array(3) {
      ["entry_id"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["name"]=>
      string(5) "Jane"
      ["images"]=>
        array(3) {
          ["image_url"]=>
          string(18) "images/jane_1.jpg"
          ["image_url"]=>
          string(18) "images/jane_2.jpg"
          ["image_url"]=>
          string(18) "images/jane_3.jpg"
        }
      }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What sort of SQL query are you using and then what are you doing on the PHP side? (Trying to work out whether you have a SQL problem or a PHP problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having tested none of this, I assume you want something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM entries INNER JOIN images ON images.entry_id = entries.entry_id
```

Then loop through those results:

```
$entries = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
{
    if (!isset($entries[$row['entry_id']]))
    {
        $row['images'] = array();
        $entries[$row['entry_id']] = $row;
    }

    $entries[$row['entry_id']]['images'][] = $row['image_url'];
}
```

Then you can loop through this return:

```
foreach ($entries as $entry)
{
    foreach ($entry['images'] as $image);
    // do something interesting
}
```

That should about do it for you, but you may have to modify some things.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great with a minor tweek: $query = "
      SELECT * FROM entries INNER JOIN images ON images.entry_id = entries.entry_id
    ";
  
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 
   
  $entries = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      if (!isset($entries[$row['entry_id']])) {
        $row['images'] = array();
        $entries[$row['entry_id']] = $row;
      }
    
      $entries[$row['entry_id']]['images'][] = $row['image_url'];
    }

Comment: great - you should accept the answer then if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your database connection code sorted?

I believe your looking for a full outer join.  Check this resource for SQL examples for the different joins.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: Oh just realised you want to group the image rows under an images column.  Your going to need to nest a select.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is something like this

```
 select * from entries, images where images.entry_id = entries.entry_id group by entries.entry_y;
```

making the join is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM entries INNER JOIN images ON images.entry_id = entries.entry_id
```

Answer (score 0):

For display array like that, you cannot use join, try this :

1. select all data in table entries
2. foreach table entries, when foreach include table images

Ex:

> $q_e = "SELECT * FROM `entries`";
>     $result_entry = mysql_query($q_e);
>
> $entries = array();
>     $images = array();
>
> while($entry = mysql_fetch_array($result_entry)) {
>
> ```
>   $q_i = "SELECT * FROM `images` WHERE `entry_id` = '".$entry['entry_id']."'";
>   $result_image = mysql_query($q_i);
>
>   while($image = mysql_fetch_array($result_image)) {
>       $images[] = array(
>           'image_url' => $image['image_url']
>       );
>   }
>
>   $entries[] = array (
>       'entry_id' => $entry['entry_id'],
>       'name' => $entry['name'],
>       'images' => $images,
>   );
> ```
>
> }
>
> echo 'pre>';var_dump($entries);